# Serializing responses in Jersey+Jackson

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson

I am trying to understand whether it is possible to serialize a java Map to a Json response from Jersey.

Here is my service :

```
@Singleton
@Path("/")
public class ApiServiceResource {
    @Inject
    ISeedingUpdateService seedingUpdateService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/map")
    public List<String> getMap() {
        return newArrayList(seedingUpdateService.toString());
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/pojo")
    public TemplateMessage getTemplateMessage(@PathParam("param") String param) {
        return new TemplateMessage(param, seedingUpdateService.toString());
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class TemplateMessage {
        public Map<String,String > param;
        public TemplateMessage() {
        }
        public TemplateMessage(String param1, String param2) {
            this.param = newHashMap();
            this.param.put(param1,param2);
        }
    }
}
```

The getMap method fails since it cannot serialize the Map -->

```
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
```

And the second method works just fine the POJO is serialized with the Map inside.

Is there something that i am missing ?

By the way the app is configured in Guice , so here is the guice configuration :

```
@Override
protected void configureServlets() {
    bind(ApiServiceResource.class);
    /* bind jackson converters for JAXB/JSON serialization */
    bind(MessageBodyReader.class).to(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
    bind(MessageBodyWriter.class).to(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
    Map<String,String> parameters = newHashMap();
    parameters.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.delver.update.api");
    serve("/rest/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, parameters);
}
```

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Guice, but, I do not see the JacksonJSON provider in your list of message body writers? I do know that Jackson can serialize maps with no additional configuration, so its quite possible your provider is simply not being registered.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding `MessageBodyWriter` (since you already have more than one) you could try what we do in our app, we bind the Jackson writer and exception mappers in Guice through:

```
bind(forName("com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider")).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
bind(forName("com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonParseExceptionMapper")).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
bind(forName("com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonMappingExceptionMapper")).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

Comment: That does not really help , it still fails on serialization of the Map

Comment: Exact same message or a different one?